# Building separate css for components in CRA app with SASS

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, jss

Working on a new project setup, and trying to get figure out the configuration to get `.scss` files to build per component. Ideally, only the necessary css files would load per component added to a page, rather than an entire combined `.css` file for all components. I know this can be done with JSS, but I believe should work with webpack in a CRA app.

My current project setup is:

/src/App.js

/src/components/

- index.js => exports all components for easy import to the page (i.e., `import {ComponentName} from './components'`)

/src/components/{component-name}

- {component-name.js}
- {component-name.scss}

Currently trying `sass@v1.56.1` and `sass-loader@13.2.0`, but not sure about the proper setup.

Might need to do a modular setup to accomplish this or just stick with JSS?